# No devolver nunca punteros a variables locales a una función

Tags: c, variables, punteros

No entiendo muy bien este concepto y he estado pensando acerca del tema.  Aclarar que el codigo funciona tanto en windows como en ubuntu pero no estoy seguro de que sea correcto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *funcion ()
{  
    int resultado=9; //variable local de la funcion, al acabar la funcion se pierde el dato
    int *puntero=&resultado; //cuando termine la funcion puntero no sabra a donde apuntar

    return *puntero; //devuelvo el valor de resultado
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int* p=funcion();
   printf("%i",p); //9

   return 0;
}
```

Si he comentado mal el programa por favor comentenlo.

Yo creo que aunque el programa funcione seria incorrecto, porque una vez acabe la funcion las variables locales almacenadas en el stack se destruyen, `puntero` no sabra a donde apuntar y podrian sobreescribirse direcciones de memoria. Ustedes que opinan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de retornar un puntero a una variable local es que, por defecto, el almacenamiento de las variables locales es en la pila, pero la pila es reutilizada una y otra vez cada vez que llamas a otras funciones.

Por tanto, si intentas acceder desde fuera de esa función a la dirección que te ha retornado, lo que encuentres allí es básicamente impredecible. Si la pila no fue reusada aún, quizás esté todavía el valor de la variable original. Si ha sido reusada estará otra variable. Incluso puede depender del compilador o del operativo (ver **actualización** más abajo).

Una forma de resolver lo anterior es poner la palabra `static` delante de la declaración de la variable. Así:

```
int *funcion() {
   static int dato;
   dato = 20;
   return &dato;
}
```

Este modificador `static` hace que el compilador reserve espacio para esta variable en el segmento de datos del programa, en lugar de la pila. El segmento de datos es donde se almacenan normalmente las variables globales, por lo que en cierto sentido esta variable `dato` es como si fuera global, sólo que no es visible desde fuera de la función. Al no estar guardada en la pila, tiene una dirección fija de memoria que puede ser retornada. Además, no es "borrada" una vez que la función retorne (la próxima vez que llames a esa función, la variable aún tendrá lo que guardaste en la ejecución anterior, por ello se puede usar para almacenar cosas como un contador de cuántas veces fue llamada la función, sin necesidad de recurrir a variables globales).

Usando `static` el comportamiento ya es predecible y el *warning* de que estás devolviendo un puntero a una variable local desaparece. No obstante, aún pueden acecharte trampas como esta:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *funcion(int valor) {
   static int dato;
   dato = valor;
   return &dato;
}

int main(){
   int *resultado1;
   int *resultado2;
   resultado1 = funcion(5);
   resultado2 = funcion(10);
   printf("resultado1 contiene %d\n", *resultado1);
   printf("resultado2 contiene %d\n", *resultado2);

   return 0;
}
```

¿Qué esperarías por pantalla? Quizás no es lo que sale... compruébalo. Si acertaste es que ya lo tienes claro :-)

### Actualización: ¿qué pasa si quito `static` del ejemplo anterior? Un rompecabezas

Lo que ocurra depende en gran medida del compilador y operativo en el que hagas la prueba. Yo he probado en tres plataformas diferentes con los siguientes resultados.

- En Ubuntu server 16.04, con `gcc` 5.4.0 el programa "rompe" con una violación de segmento. Esto ocurre porque aparentemente gcc ha decidido que si una función retorna un puntero a su pila, en lugar de retornar esa dirección, el compilador la cambia por 0. Es decir, la función retorna un puntero nulo. El intento de usarlo después para ver su valor causa el *segfault*.
- En OSX (Darwin 17.5.0), con `gcc` 4.2.1 (versión de Apple 9.10), el programa no rompe, y muestra siempre 10 en el primer `printf()` y 0 en el segundo.
- En Ubuntu server 14.04 con `gcc` 4.8.4, el programa tampoco rompe y muestra 10 en el primer `printf()` y un número diferente cada vez (alrededor de 32600) en el segundo `printf()`.

El comportamiento de los dos últimos casos merece una explicación.

Cuando omitimos `static`, la dirección que retornamos es una dirección dentro de la pila. No obstante la pila es una zona de la memoria que se reutiliza. Cada vez que invocamos una función, en la pila se guardan los parámetros que se le pasan, la dirección de retorno, y los registros que el compilador decida apilar como parte de la entrada a la función. Encima de esos datos, se crea espacio para las variables locales de la función. Toda esta información conforma lo que se llama un "marco de pila". Si desde esa función se llama a otra, un nuevo marco se crea encima del anterior. Cuando una función retorna, su marco de pila es "liberado", en el sentido de que el puntero de pila retrocede al marco anterior.

Revisemos el código:

```
   resultado1 = funcion(5);
   resultado2 = funcion(10);
   printf("resultado1 contiene %d\n", *resultado1);
   printf("resultado2 contiene %d\n", *resultado2);
```

Cuando llamamos por primera vez a `funcion(5)` se crea un marco de pila con el parámetro que le pasemos, la dirección de retorno (apuntando a la siguiente instrucción dentro de `main()`), las variables locales de `funcion()` y el resto de cosas que decida meter el compilador. La función copia su parámetro (5) a su variable local y retorna la dirección de esa variable local, que apunta a una dirección dentro de su marco de pila. Pero cuando la función retorna, ese marco es "liberado". Mientras no llamemos a otra función el antiguo marco aún está en memoria (pues aunque se libera, no se borra), por lo que aún podríamos ir a `*resultado1` y ver allí un 5.

Sin embargo al llamar a `funcion(10)` la segunda vez, se crea un nuevo marco de pila que *sobreescribe* al anterior, y por tanto (y ya que en este caso el marco de pila será idéntico en estructura porque estoy llamando a la misma función), en la dirección a que apuntaba `resultado1` se guardará un 10. El puntero `resultado2` apuntará a la misma dirección que `resultado1`, por lo que cualquiera de los dos mostraría 10.

Es por eso que, tanto en OSX como en Ubuntu 16.04, el primer `printf()` muestra 10 en lugar de 5. Pero... ¿por qué el segundo printf no muestra también 10?

La razón es que al llamar al primer `printf()`¡estamos invocando una función! Y por tanto **estamos reescribiendo el marco de pila otra vez**. En la dirección `direccion1` (o `direccion2`, pues son iguales) veremos ahora lo que sea que el primer `printf()` haya necesitado guardar en sus variables locales. Aparentemente en OSX es siempre un cero, mientras que en Ubuntu 16.04 es un número variable (probablemente parte de algún puntero, pues el cargador de linux aleatoriza las direcciones en las que carga el programa y así los valores de los punteros son diferentes en cada ejecución).

Comment: este codigo es una trampa mortal xD. Cuando vi el codigo por primera vez me dije a mi mismo 5 y 10 pero mi sorpresa fue que obtuve 10 y 10. Despues me pare a pensar en static y y en esos dos printf seguidos. En la primera funcion dato es una variable local con static lo que quiere decir que su valor en vez de perderse cuando acaba la funcion seguira conservandolo ya que esta en la memoria estatica no en la pila.

Comment: La primera vez que la llamamos resultado1=funcion(5) efectivamente va a valer 5 y la segunda vez que la llamamos efectivamente va a valer 10. Y precisamente como vale 10 en esa ultima llamada a la funcion y su valor no se pierde hasta que termine el programa pues por eso sale 10 y 10. Espero que este bien lo que dicho...

Comment: Sin embargo si quitamos el static el codigo no va y es precisamente por el titulo de esta pregunta "No devolver nunca punteros a variables locales a una función" si no me equivoco

Comment: He probado el codigo varias veces en el mismo entorno  (Ubuntu server 14.04, gcc 4.8.4) y cada vez que lo ejecuto resultado2 tiene un valor diferente, hasta el printf parece ir todo bien resultado1 y resultado2 tienen la direccion de dato sin embargo creo yo que es en el printf cuanfo falla

Comment: Que esta pasando??

Comment: El numero ese que sale diferente cada vez es por el rango del tipo short o es totalmente aleatorio?

Comment: Entonces estariamos sobreescribiendo valores en la pila no?

Comment: gracias por la explicacion

Comment: @eduu15 me ha parecido que todo esto que hablamos en los comentarios está mejor como parte de la respuesta, así que la he editado y borrado los comentarios. Revisa también los tuyos para eliminar los que ya no son relevantes.

Answer (score 2):

> Ustedes que opinan?

Ese código no tiene sentido pero no por lo que tu piensas:

`*puntero` te va a devolver un entero, mientras que el tipo de retorno de la función es un puntero a `int`... los tipos no concuerdan.

Si el código lo dejas así:

```
int funcion ()
{  
    int resultado=9; 
    int *puntero=&resultado; 

    return *puntero;
}
```

La función será equivalente a esta otra:

```
int funcion ()
{  
    int resultado=9; 

    return resultado;
}
```

Porque lo que está devolviendo la función es el valor almacenado en `resultado` y, para ello, se hace una copia del mismo... lo que les pase luego a `resultado` y `puntero` es irrelevante ya que ya has conseguido una copia del dato que a ti te interesaba.

Un escenario completamente diferente lo encontraríamos si hacemos esto:

```
int *funcion ()
{  
    int resultado=9; 
    int *puntero=&resultado; 

    return puntero;
}
```

Esta función podríamos simplificarla así:

```
int *funcion ()
{  
    int resultado=9; 

    return &resultado;
}
```

Y esta versión sí sería problemática porque no estamos devolviendo un valor sino una referencia a un elemento que no va a existir.

Podemos intentar forzar el error con un código tal que:

```
int* func()
{
  int * ptr;

  {
   int var[10] = {1};
  }

  {
    int var[10] = {2};
    ptr = &var;
  }

  {
    int var[10] = {3};
  }

  return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char const ** argv)
{
  int* ptr = func();
  printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

Dependiendo del compilador, el programa final podrá imprimir `1`, `2` o `3` u otra cosa si la implementación de `printf` sobreescribe la pila... todo dependerá de las optimizaciones que aplique el compilador.

¿Por qué usar arrays? Porque si uso variables locales el compilador puede ubicarlas en registros del sistema en vez de en la pila... y nada le impide usar registros diferentes para cada variable... esta es una forma de intentar forzar a que las variables se ubiquen en la pila y así materializar la inconsistencia.

Comment: gracias ahora lo entiendo

Comment: Si usas una variable local a la que referencias con `&` veo muy raro que el compilador vaya a usar un registro para ella, pues en ese caso ¿qué devolvería el operador `&`?

Comment: @abulafia no tengo ahora mismo tiempo para meterme a ver cómo optimiza cada compilador un caso así... la primera versión que he hecho con variables simples ha sido más estable que esta otra y por eso no la he puesto. Yo al principio pensé lo mismo que tu pero los resultados eran diferentes y mi intención es que se viesen facilmente resultados distintos al cambiar de compilador...